# Django ForeignKey form field widget

Tags: python, django, forms

First of all I have tried to research my problem but have not been able to find what I need. My problem might be related to the design of my project (any help would be appreciated).

The problem I am facing is as follows:

- I have a few models
- I have a model that would be used specifically to create a ModelForm
- In this model I have ForeignKey field that is represented by default as a select/option input widget in the ModelForm (for each  the value attribute is the ForeignKey and text between the tags is the `__str__()` of the model the ForeignKey points to. The user sees the `__str__()` and value attribute of the option tag is submitted which is great).
- So far so good but I want to replace the widget with an input text field so I can implement it as a search field.
- Now when the user submits the form the string entered in the text input field is submitted and of course django doesn't like that since it expects a foreign key

I already can think of a few solutions to the problem and I am sure I can make it work but each of them feels like I would be violating some best practices. So my question is what should I do?

- Do I exclude this particular field from the ModelForm and implement it as an input text field then after form submission make a query with it's value and then store the ForeignKey to the DB
- Do I manipulate the data with JavaScript upon submission so that Django receives correct information
- Can I clean this fields data with Django and transform it from string to FK?
- Am I going the wrong way with this or there is a Django feature for this type of situation?

Comment: So you want a search feature that links to the options of your select field? Or do you want the user to be able to submit the search data as it appears in the input box?

Comment: Create an autocomplete Ajax search field, which queries the Database, collects the id and adds it to the form value.

Comment: @MatthewR. The plan was to let the user submit the data as it appears in the input box and then change it with Django so it can be place in the model

Comment: @petkostas That sounds like a neat solution, I am going to try it

Thank you both for the help!

Regarding the initial plan for changing the data with Django - I tried to define a `clean_<fieldname>()` method and return the foreign key instead of the string. It didn't work. What I found is that this field doesn't get in the `cleaned_data` at all. Probably an earlier step in the validation process is not validating it. Could it be that? And would it work if change this form field type (since it's a `ModelForm` the default form field is `ModelChoiceField`)

Comment: @petkostas Now that I think about it, if I make an Ajax call and add the id to the form value it will change what the user sees (the user should see a string that means something not an id from the DB)

Comment: You could use a dummy element (something like a span, similar to tags for example) and assign the id to a hidden actual valid element. There are many different ways to approach this, another one could be a multi select field.

Comment: True there are many ways to make it work. I am just trying to find which is the most sensible. I think I got it to work:
- I redefine the form field as pointed by the Django doc: [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) to a `CharField`
- Then the `clean_<fieldname>`() method gets executed properly where I make a query to find the id to the DB

I guess that was what I was trying to do. If anyone knows a better way to handle this situation I would be happy to hear it. Should I mark this question as answered?

Comment: Alright so my form `is_valid()` returns True but I cannot save it to the db with `form.save()`... I get a `ValueError`: `Cannot assign "4":` ... and then it says it must be a model instance. So I think I might be messing with the form when I only change the `cleaned_data` field that I want. What am I missing?
 
Also what is `form.save()` doing exactly? What objects/fields in the `form` object does it look for to save it to the DB.

Comment: I think.... I might have it working finally.... so it turns I do have to return a model instance from the `clean_<fieldname>()` method. If I don't encounter any other problems I will mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem here is the solution (to my problem at least):
I tried to use the `clean_<fieldname>` method to change the user entered string to database id. The method wasn't executing because the validation process was stopping earlier because of the difference between the form field and the widget. I redefined the form field to `CharField` so that step of the validation was working and then the `clean_<fieldname>` method executes without a problem.